# Получить Process ID по Process handle

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Предположим, у нас есть **hProcess**, получаемый функцией **OpenProcess** (или GetCurrentProcess, что не суть важно). Как нам, имея только этот хэндл, узнать **Process ID** того процесса, который был открыт через OpenProcess?

Answer (score 2):

```
DWORD WINAPI GetProcessId(
  _In_  HANDLE Process
);
```